# What version is the Kerbal Space Program demo?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm getting into Kerbal Space Program. I've been playing the demo and looking at youtube videos, but the youtube videos look SO different to what I've been playing. Does anyone know what version (or how old) the demo is?

The biggest difference I've noticed is in Kerbin textures. Mine are just a green blur but in the youtube videos there are textures, trees, etc. Also water looks way better... I'm pretty sure my video settings are up all the way.

Comment: I believe the last version released was based off of .13; many, MANY improvements have been made since then.

Comment: @fbueckert If you leave that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @fbueckert the demo version is a stripped down variant of 0.18.(I think)4. It replaced 0.13 because that was no longer even remotely representative. Of course 0.20 brought major changes again.

Comment: Is this even a bug? Maybe somewhere close to the current version of the full game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to their [blog](http://kerbaldevteam.tumblr.com/post/42955050444/new-ksp-demo-out-now), the latest version of the demo is based off of 0.18.2.  This means you have docking, which was added in .18.  There are some restrictions from the full version, though:

- Part loading limited to the 25 stock ones.
- No Plugin loading.
- SPH and Runway Facilities are inaccessible.
- Only one save profile allowed.
- Cannot launch new flights if 3 or more are already in progress.
- Kerbin, the Mun and the Sun are the only celestial bodies in the solar system.

You should be able to see the version in the bottom right corner of the main screen, once the game has loaded.  Currently, you're at least two versions behind.